# Can I use rrdtool with Perl to make graphs from CSV files?

Tags: perl, csv, rrdtool

Below is the sample data format in my CSV file.

```
date,<options>
YYYY-MM-DD,<values>
```

Every next morning this CSV file has been updated with next date values. Can I use rrdtool to create graphs, and if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [RRD::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?RRD::Simple) - simple interface to create and store data in RRD files and look at [RRD::Simple::Examples](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?RRD::Simple::Examples) - Examples using RRD::Simple

Answer (score 1):

[`RRDTool::OO`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?RRDTool::OO) is an excellent module with lots of documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The rrdtool tutorial actually starts you out by having you read data points from a text file into rrdtool's database.  This should be a good jumping off point for figuring out a solution to your problem.

http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/tut/rrdtutorial.en.html